# iPad - multiple UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have UINavigationController and I`ve placed UIListView in it. Now I want to add multiple BarButtons to left side of navigation bar. How is that possible? I managed to add one button there via code but not multiple.

**Edit:** Buttons added via IB to NavigationBar of UINavigationController aren`t visible at all. What could cause the problem?

I`ve created UINavigationController in .h file and used this in .m and pushed another view (that TableView):

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

tableOfContents *tableOfContentsViewController = [[tableOfContents alloc] init];
[navigationController pushViewController:tableOfContentsViewController animated:NO];
[tableOfContentsViewController release];
```

**Edit 2:** I solved second problem. So the first question only remains. Multiple BarButtonItems ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 5.0 has apis to do this. Check the following properties of [UINavigationItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html) Class

```
leftBarButtonItems
```

`rightBarButtonItems`

```
leftItemsSupplementBackButton
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do this is to add the UIBarButtonItem to a UIToolBar and make a UIBarButtonItem with the UIToolBar as the customView.

There are many examples on the web, check out:
http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html